# Automated reply with a link on slack

Tags: slack

I'm making a script to monitor a 3D printer in the next room for a colleague. Using bash to take a picture, then upload to Dropbox.

He would like to be able to call a command ("/monitor or @monitor") to get the Dropbox link on slack but I cannot seem to find a relatively easy way to do this. Is there an app or not for those simple task?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is outgoing webhooks. Which is documented very well at https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks.

Basically you get POST data on your web server, and you reply to it in JSON.

I use python flask and ngnix to accomplish very similar task.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement a custom command on Slack using "slash commands". Every time you enter "\monitor" (or any other command you want to define) in Slack it will trigger a custom app that you then can connect to your bash scripts. You can also provide additional parameters in the command.

Check here for the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands).